# Can I make the import package only check for the package if that class or function is called?

Tags: python, function, import, package, call

I only want to import a package when the function using that package is called. Is there any way I can do this

```
class metarmap:
import metar_map as mm
import neopixel
import board


def __init__(self, airport):
    pass

def __repr__(self):
    return str('Hey Dont import noepixel or board til I call the .metarmap method!')
```

Comment: You can make imports associated with conditional statements.

Answer (score 1):

You may not know this but `import` statements are still statements, this means you could do something like this:

```
<code here>
if <condition>:
    import <package>
```

and it'd be very valid

Comment: I like that idea, is it possible that I could potentially say if function is called?

Comment: It depends, do you call the function yourself? or does another component call it, if that's the case, does it call it conditionally? or unconditionally?
Meaning if you call the function yourself, you could just plug the `import` statement right after the function call wherever that may be,
if another component calls that function, check where that component is called and if EVERY SINGLE TIME that component is called it executes that function you could plug the `import` statement right after that component is called

Comment: I see what you're saying, that clarified and its all working now. Thanks!